# Facebook like box localisation

Tags: facebook-like

I made multilanguage website with WPML, on WP CMS. Now I need to translate facebook like box, but I dont have any idea how to do it.

The idea was to echo 3 different language facebook like boxes, but I couldnt find how to change like box language..

Is it possible to set fb like box language in script/html? If not, how to make it multilanguage  in other way?

Comment: I thought the Button changes his language by connecting to facebook servers.

Comment: Its really possible to make like box multilanguage. But i dunno how ;/